# Send URL encoded data instead of JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

Is it possible to POST "url encoded" parameters to a remote web service instead of JSON or XML ?

My rails application consumes a web service which takes URL encoded parameters (content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded) in POST requests and give JSON answers.

Is this kind of RESTful services common ?

Answer (score 2):

When you make a hit to a JSON or XML web service using Ajax then the parameters are just getting encoded as either GET or POST, and is typically sent using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type anyway (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for an example specific to jQuery).

So, basically, yes, it is possible to send data in any format (JSON, XML, BSON etc.) in this manner.

Comment: What would be a clean solution to achieve that with activeresource ?

I haven't thought that much about that but I think I can just write a custom serializer. Does it seem to be an overkill ?